# Jquery selecting TEXT part of LI apart from other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to process in jQuery a large number of `li` elements where each has a `<b></b>` element followed by the text of the `li`. See the code:

```js
$("li b").wrap(function() {
    return '<font color="blue">' + $( this ).text() + '</font>';
});
$("li::innerText").wrap(function() {
    return '<font color="red">' + $(this).innerHTML() + "</font>";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><b>hello</b>xxx</li>
</ul>
```

In the above example I need the word `hello` to be wrapped in blue and the word `xxx` wrapped in red.

Here is what I would like the "result" html to be:

```
<ul>
   <li><font color="blue"><b>hello</b></font><font color="red">xxx</font></li>
</ul>
```

Note: I have simplified my problem. The actually wrapping will be more complex (so a CSS solution is not what I am looking for).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make the entire `li` color red. Then just override that with blue for the `b` element.

Comment: do you have more than one `li` ? can you please post expected HTML result ?

Comment: I am looking for a jquery way for wrapping the TEXT part of an LI. I will add expected HTML.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best way I could do it:

```
$( "li" ).html(function(index, oldHtml) {
    var pos = oldHtml.indexOf('</b>');
    var result = '<font color="blue">' + oldHtml.substring(0, pos+5) + '</font>'
     + '<font color="red">' + oldHtml.substring(pos+5) + '</font>';
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a CSS solution, the following would work.

```
var lis = $("li");

for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++){
    var li = $("li").eq(i);
    var b = li.find("b").detach();
    li.wrapInner("<span style='color:red'>");
    b.css("color", "blue");
    li.prepend(b);
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/cpw88b1z/

Comment: Thanks, but this solution wraps the whole li with the color:red and I am looking for something that will wrap ONLY the text part of it

Comment: If the answers given aren't helping you, might need to show more code even if it's more complex.

Comment: I don't think more code is needed. I am simply looking for the jquery code that can wrap the two elements inside the li separately: the <b></b> and the text of the li. e.g hello and xxx

Comment: Updated answer. Hopefully that's more what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in full jQuery or a mix of jQuery and pure javaScript.

The [font tag is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) so I substituted with span.

First solution:

```js
$(function () {
  $("li b").wrap('<span style="color: blue;"/>');
  $('li').contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType === 3;}).wrap('<span style="color: red;"/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
    <li><b>hello</b>xxx</li>
</ul>
```

The mixed solution:

```js
$(function () {
  $('li').contents().each(function(index, element) {
    if (this.tagName === 'B') {
      this.innerHTML = '<span style="color: blue;">' + this.innerHTML + '</span>';
    } else {
      if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        var temp = document.createElement('font');
        temp.innerHTML = '<span style="color: red;">' + this.data + '</span>';
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(temp, this);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li><b>hello</b>xxx</li>
</ul>
```